# Get innerHTML of upper node when nested node is value

Tags: javascript

How do you loop through the NodeList to retrieve the value `item` when the value of the c tag = `text` ?

**html**

```
<td class="one">
  <div>
    <b>
      <span>item</span>
    </b>
    <div>
      <c>text</c>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

**javascript**

```
search = "text";
data = document.querySelectorAll(".one, b span, c");
for (i=0; i<data.length; i++)
{
  txt=data[i].innerHTML;
  //console.log(txt)

  // not empty
  if (txt) {
    //indexOf [position] returns -1 if not found 
    var s = txt.indexOf(search);
    if (s  > -1) {
      console.log(txt)
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the relevant cells, and check their descendants:

```
var search, list, index, span, c;
search = "text";
list = document.querySelectorAll(".one");
for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
    c = list[index].querySelector("c");
    if (c && c.innerHTML.indexOf(search) !== -1) {
        span = list[index].querySelector("b span");
        if (span) {
            console.log(span.innerHTML);
        }
    }
}
```

---

I will just note that `b` and `c` are not valid HTML, but I assume they stand in for something...

Comment: Wish I could vote twice just for that `var search, list, index, span, c;`